# My mv command is showing no such file or directory when renaming a file

Tags: linux, unix, file-rename, mv

In the below code I am renaming a file with a date field addition to it.but the error says no such file or directory.its doing the moving operation instead of renaming it.
Thanks.

```
#!bin/bash

cd /some/directory/name

LIST=$(ls)

for FILE in $LIST
do
 DATE=$(date +%d/%m/%y/%H:%M:%S)
 VARX=$(echo $FILE | cut - d '.' -f 1)
 VARY=$(echo $FILE | cut - d '.' -f 2)
NNAME="${VARX}""${DATE}"."${VARY}"

mv "${FILE}" "${NNAME}";
done
```

Comment: What is the name of the file that it fails to move?

Comment: You should correct your tags so that it includes bash

Answer (score 1):

you missed a space when using the cut command, instaed of - d you should write -d like

```sh
#!bin/bash

cd /some/directory/name

LIST=$(ls)

for FILE in $LIST
do
 DATE=$(date +%d%m%y%H%M%S)
 VARX=$(echo $FILE | cut -d '.' -f 1)
 VARY=$(echo $FILE | cut -d '.' -f 2)
NNAME="${VARX}""${DATE}"."${VARY}"

mv "${FILE}" "${NNAME}";
done
```

Have a good day !

Comment: Actually I got the fix.the forward slash(/) in my date variable was causing the issue.shell was looking for a path because of the forward slash.thank you.